# Очистка виджета в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть ли способ чтобы при нажатии, например, кнопки всё как бы стиралось и в пустом приложении уже выполнялось какое-то действие.То есть очищался экран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def clear_widgets():
    for w in widgets:
        w.clear()

button_clear = QPushButton('очистить')
button_clear.clicked.connect(clear_widgets)
```